# using FFTW compatablity mode in cuFFT

Tags: cuda, fftw, cufft

I have a full project created using FFTW. I want to transition to using cuFFT. I understand that cuFFT has a "compatibility mode". But how exactly does this work? [The cuFFT manual](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cufft/index.html#fftw-supported-interface) says:

> After an application is working using the FFTW3 interface, users may
>   want to modify their code to move data to and from the GPU and use the
>   routines documented in the FFTW Conversion Guide for the best
>   performance.

Does this mean I actually need to change my individual function calls? For example, call
`cufftPlan1d()` instead of `fftw_plan_dft_1d()`.

Do I also have to change my data types?

```
    fftw_complex *inputData;    // fftw data storage gets replaced..
    cufft_complex *inputData;   // ... by cufft data storage?

    fftw_plan forwardFFT;       // fftw plan gets replaced...
    cufftHandle forwardFFT;     // ... by cufft plan?
```

If I'm going to have to rewrite all of my code, what is the point of `cufftSetCompatabilityMode(.)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably what you want is the [cuFFTW interface to cuFFT](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cufft/index.html#fftw-supported-interface).  I suggest you read this documentation as it probably is close to what you have in mind.  This will allow you to use cuFFT in a FFTW application with a minimum amount of changes.  As indicated in the documentation, there should only be two steps requred:

- It is recommended that you replace the include file `fftw3.h` with `cufftw.h`
- Instead of linking with the double/single precision libraries such as fftw3/fftw3f libraries, link with both the CUFFT and CUFFTW libraries

Regarding the doc item you excerpted, that step (moving the data explicitly) is not required if you're just using the cuFFTW compatibility interface.  However, you may not achieve maximum performance this way.   If you want to achieve maximum performance, you may need to use cuFFT natively, for example so that you can explicitly manage data movement.  Whether or not this is important will depend on the specific structure of your application (how many FFT's you are doing, and whether any data is shared amongst multiple FFTs, for example.)   If you intend to use cuFFT natively, then the following comments apply:

Yes, you need to change your individual function calls.  They must line up with function names in the API, associated header files, and library.  The `fftw_` function names are not in the cuFFT library.

You can inspect your data types and should discover that for the basic data types like `float`, `double`, complex, etc. they should be layout-compatible between cuFFT and FFTW.  Personally I would recommend changing your data types to cuFFT data types, but there should be no functional or performance difference at this time.

Although you don't mention it, cuFFT will also require you to move the data between CPU/Host and GPU, a concept that is not relevant for FFTW.

Regarding `cufftSetCompatibilityMode`, the [function documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cufft/index.html#function-cufftsetcompatibilitymode) and discussion of [FFTW compatibility mode](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cufft/index.html#fftw-compatibility-mode) is pretty clear on it's purpose.  It has to do with overall data layout, especially padding of data for FFTW.

Comment: So `cufftSetCompatabilityMode()` is only relevant if I'm using native cuFFT? The first parameter for that method is a cuFFT Handle, which presumably I don't have if I'm using FFTW. Is it possible to "intermix" the two? For example, use the interface for everything except "execute" and then use native cuFFT for the "execute"? 

Also, if I'm using just the interface, is there a way to get the function return values (i.e. CUFFT_SUCCESS)?

Comment: Yes, `cufftSetCompatibilityMode()` is not relevant if you are *strictly* using the cuFFTW interface.  Yes, it's possible to mix the 2 APIs.  You can't use the FFTW interface for everything except "execute" because it does not effect the data copy process unless you actually execute with the FFTW interface.  The cuFFT "execute" assumes the data is already copied.  I don't know how to get the function return values using strictly the cuFFTW interface.  However for supported fftw functions, any kind of status parameters should also be supported.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link out :
Here, it says that all we need to do is change the linking.

https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/cudacasts-episode-8-accelerate-fftw-apps-cufft-55/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).